# How to append a record in core data entity having relation one to many

Tags: swift, core-data

I have two entities of Mobile and User in which Mobile has attribute name and user also has a attribute of name. User can has multiple mobile but mobile has can only one user. Scenario is that when ever I enter a name for user which is already present in User entity it should update that user.mobile set rather than duplicating a new user. 
These are my save and fetch functions

```
    func save () {
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved succesfully")
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

func fetch<T: NSManagedObject>( _ objectType: T.Type) -> [T] {
    let  entityName = String(describing: objectType)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)

    do {
        let fetchedObjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [T]
        return fetchedObjects ?? [T]()
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return [T]()
    }
}
```

This is how i am adding

```
       users = persistenceManager.fetch(User.self)
    if users.count > 1 {
    for val in users {

        if val.name == "Umar" {
            val.addToDevice(device)
            device.user = val
            persistenceManager.save()
        }
        else if val.name != nil  {
                            user.name = "Umar"
                            user.addToDevice(device)
            device.user = user
            persistenceManager.save()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks some details. BUt let me assume I understand you correctly.

```
    let userName = "some name from user input"
    let user = MOUser.getUser(context, name: userName, createIfMissing: true)
    // here you have user with name required and not duplicated if already exists
device.user = user
```

And add static function either to your user class or to db coordinator

```
    static func getUser(moc: NSMaagedObjectContext, name: String, createIfMissing: Bool) -> MOUser? {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<MOUser> = MOUser.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(#keyPath(MOUser.name)) = %@", name)
        request.fetchLimit = 1
        var result: MOUser? = (try? moc.fetch(request))?.first

        if result == nil && createIfMissing {
            result = MOUser(context: moc)
            result?.name = name
        }
        return result
    }
```